# Bulk insert data entity framework 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Normally In my previous project, I can do bulk insert by passing a list of object as code below

```
public void Create(List<ApplicationUserRole> item)
{           
        foreach (var data in item)
        {
            _dbContext.ApplicationUserRole.Add(data);
        }
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();           
}
```

But for now i keep hitting error

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type
>   'Docdoc.Models.ApplicationUserRole' cannot be tracked because another
>   instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. For
>   new entities consider using an IIdentityGenerator to generate unique
>   key values.

I need change my code at below to work

```
    foreach (var data in item)
    {
        _dbContext.ApplicationUserRole.Add(data);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I know It is very bad practice. The performance will be very slow by insert large amount of data

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: The exception you are getting is saying you are violating your Key for the table. Why don't you correct this first. Also what is Large amounts are data.As if i was calling ApplicationUserRole... in my systsem i would probably not have more than 1000 roles. so large amounts of data what are we talking about here... 1000 roles added this way will take less than 1 sec.

Comment: Hi Seabizkit  this is only one of the example. I still got other table need to bulk insert. And yes I know is the key error.  But what is the solution? Please dont ask why not google. I had googling few hour and still no solution.Thanks

Comment: hey man... here to help. solution... inspect the data... find the spot where these ApplicationUserRole are added to List<ApplicationUserRole>...  showing that code will help. Also show the class for ApplicationUserRole so i can see what makes up the KEY. Bulk inserts are a different question i  feel and is secondary to this. Maybe you could ask that as a separate question. Key to making it perform fast... try and create a context per unit of work(UOW). a UOW can be small.... the bigger the context gets the slower it gets... just keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception message you saw may not be fixed by calling "SaveChanges" after each Add. The root cause of your problem is that your instance of DbContext already has a ApplicationUserRole entity with the same key (guessing it is  ApplicationUserRole.Id or something). [This error is common](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/search?q=tracked+because+another+instance+of+this+type&type=Issues) and is often caused by manually setting temporary key values, e.g. setting ApplicationUserRole.Id to -1. (See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4488 for example.)

If the error is *not* being caused by incorrectly setting temp key values, then also make sure your instance of DbContext is short-lived and only used in one thread. In other words, use DbContext for one operation only.

```
public void Create(List<ApplicationUserRole> item)
{         
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {  
        context.ApplicationUserRole.AddRange(data);
        context.SaveChanges();  
    }         
}
```